# Set Toolbar layout direction to RTL, with `supportsRtl="false"`

Tags: android, layout, android-toolbar, right-to-left

I have a special situation that I am not able to find a solution for. I am trying to force a view to be laid-out in RTL, but one of the restrictions is that `supportsRtl` must be `false` in the manifest.

```
<!-- AndroidManifest.xml -->
<application android:supportsRtl="false">

<!-- layout/activity.xml -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The problem I'm having is that `android:layoutDirection` and `View#setLayoutDirection(int)` are ignored unless `supportsRtl="true"`. Short of making my own `Toolbar`, what other options are there for handling this?

Comment: I would suggest to create a custom view and extends Toolbar class and override method hasRtlSupport to always return true (regardless manifest). However, that method is private and can not be overridden :(

Comment: I have the same situation. Even `setLayoutDirection` cant override that.